# WebDriver click a link with multiple classes (css)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

I have an element with multiple classes like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
  <td>
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want to click it with:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.className("btn btn-primary btn-xs")).click();
```

but this one doesn't work -> exception: No element found

I try with this:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='btn btn-primary btn-xs']")).click();
```

this one works, but it just moves the mouse to this element, it doesn't really click on it.

How can I actually click on it? Thanks

Comment: What method/selector you used to find an element, should have no influence on what happens when you call the click method ...

Comment: What element does enclose your link? It can intercept your click.

Comment: @AlexeyR. the link is enclosed in a table. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @LouisT IMO, The sample HTML which you provided is an invalid HTML. Within `tr` attribute, 3 nos of `td` have opened while only 1no `td` got closed. Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You need to create an unique `cssSelector` or `xpath` which identifies an element. The following `cssSelector` and `xpath` will locate the WebElement and perform `click()` on it.

**CSS**:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs")).click();
```

**XPATH**:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-primary btn-xs']")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. cssSelector has Exception: Given CSS is invalid. and your xpath also has the same behaviour like my code, it just moves the mouse to that element. I updated my question, this link is enclosed by a table

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake in the previous `cssSelector` that I provided within my Answer but I have fixed/updated it. In their current format both the `cssSelector` and `xpath` are equivalent. If it still doesn't clicks you may have to consider to take help of `Actions` Class. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I used `JavascriptExecutor` as workaround, and it works as expected. Thanks